# Windows C: the inverse of CreateMapFile

Tags: c, windows, handle

I have a rather odd program where I need to load a file into memory, close that file handle, and then use the file image in memory like a file (where i use ReadFile, WriteFile with a HANDLE)... so basically I'm looking at doing the inverse of CreateMapFile... is this possible within the Windows API?

Thanks!

Comment: What about a temporary file? What is known as memory mapped file in Windows API is not available for `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` API.

Comment: You'll need Detours to replace Read/WriteFile() with your custom routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `CreateFile`, you can use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`. This *attempts* to hold the data for the file in RAM if possible, but it does *not* guarantee it -- the data could be written out to disk if memory gets low enough.